# Why is asking for iPhone Distribution?

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, identity

I'm using Xode 4, and i have recently uploaded my first app... but now i want to start making upgrades, idk what did i move but now i got always this:

```
    Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile
```

I use 2 accounts, anyways i deleted all files according to keys and certificates, and did the process again... i started btw with the error of not getting correct build identifier, wich now evolved in this code sign error. Anyone have any idea? im using debug scheme (or that), i deleted my "distribution", but idk why it says 'iPhone Distribution' instead something else... don anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Keychain app, select the 'Certificates' option in the left-hand panel and check that you have something like this:

[image]

You should see an iPhone Distribution certificate with a green tick to say that it is valid and an 'Apple Worldwide Developer' certificate.

Then open Organizer from Xcode, select the 'Devices' tab and then select 'Developer Profile' on the left:

[image]

Check that you have an iPhone Distribution identity in the right-hand panel.

Select Provisioning Profiles in the left-hand panel and check that you have a distribution profile in the right-hand panel.

[image]

Report back and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Errmm - well you need to tell me what you found. Did everything look as it is supposed to?

Comment: Yes everything is done fine and without exceptions, i think ive done all the process like 3 times or more... but its missing something, maybe i changed something in an archive like the phlist